# Using Regular Expressions in Diagram Filters

Tags: visualization, enterprise-architect

I want to track changes with different Projects in Enterprise Architect. 
The Project re-uses a multitude of architectural components in multiple instances. To track these dependencies we use a Tag in the Notes-Section of the component.

I would like to use the diagram filter to highlight components belonging to a certain sub-project with a tag in its "Notes" section.

Example:
Component 1 has "Proj_0805" in its Notes-Section
Component 2 has "Proj_0905, Proj_0805" in its Notes-Section
Component 3 has "" in its Notes-Section

Using the diagram filter i can highlight components with "Proj_0805". 
I would like to be able to combine Highlighting-Conditions. For example highlight "Proj_.*"

Is there a way to do this with Enterprise Architect?

Cheers,

Comment: I doubt they ever heard of RE to exist.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you can do that.

But of course you can send a [feature request](http://sparxsystems.com/support/forms/feature_request.html) to Sparx to ask for it.